# C singly linked list Seg fault with gcc but not dcc

Tags: c

[image: Added screenshot with output and example txt file]I am trying to read words from a txt file into a singly linked list and show the list.

I compile using: `gcc -Wall -lm -std=c11 *.c -o showList` (I have other c files), and there's a segmentation fault when I run `./showList`.

However the list displays fine and no seg fault if I compile using: `dcc -Wall -lm -std=c11 *.c -o showList`

I'm new to C and this really confuses me, any help or suggestion would be much appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct ListNode *List;
typedef struct ListNode {
    char *data;  
    struct ListNode *next;
}ListNode;

List getListFromFile(void);
void showList (List L);
List listInsert (List L, char *word);

int main (int argc, char **argv){
    List list = getListFromFile();
    showList(list); //seg fault here?
}

List getListFromFile(void) {
    List newList = NULL;
    FILE *txtFile;
    txtFile = fopen("someRandom.txt", "r"); // word1 word2 word3 word4
    if(txtFile == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error opening txt\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    char word[100];
    while(fscanf(txtFile, "%s", word) != EOF){ //read from txt file and store words into list
        printf("%s ", word); // testing
        newList = listInsert(newList, word);
    }
    fclose(txtFile);
    return newList;
}

void showList (List L){
    if (L == NULL) return;
    while (L != NULL) {
        printf("%s ", L->data);
        L = L->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

static ListNode *newListNode (char *word) {
    ListNode *n = malloc (sizeof (*n));
    if (n == NULL) err (EX_OSERR, "err creating node \n"); 
    n->data = strdup (word);
    n->next = NULL;
    return n;
}

List listInsert (List L, char *word){ //insert at head
    ListNode *n = newListNode(word);
    if (L == NULL) {
        return n;
    } else { 
        n->next = L;
        return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: When this file is compiled by itself and run with a dummy input file with a couple of strings in it, it runs fine.  Please give an example input file that causes it to crash.  Also, try compiling the file by itself.

Comment: Suggest `fscanf(txtFile, "%s", word) != EOF` --> `fscanf(txtFile, "%99s", word) == 1`

Comment: A sample file could be words.txt with (
word1 word62 word84  
    word84  
 word6 word9 word42 
), When I add in a line: printf("list rdy \n"); before showList() in main, it would output: word1 word62 word84... list rdy \n Segmentation fault , but however if I remove this line: printf("list rdy \n"), it wouldn't print anything and would just output: Segmentation fault

Comment: Did you try compiling just this file instead of multiple?  You shouldn't need more that the one single file.  Also, try including `stdlib.h` for the `malloc` function.

Comment: I've desk checked your code, and most of the linked list code looks fine. Your LL code is better than most that a first timer OP posts here. I think that if you apply the fixes that chux and dbush suggested, things will work. AFAICT, any of those fixes could be an issue. So, compile as single file, _fix_ the `fscanf`, and add the `#include`.

Comment: It works fine if I put all my functions from other .c files into this main c file, but if I were to put everything back and #include these files(List.h, readData.h), gcc still gives seg fault whereas dcc doesn't.

Comment: So what you showed us isn't your actual code.  You need to show us the **exact** code that's causing the problem.  But first, try `#include <string.h>` in List.c and see if the problem goes away.  Don't ignore warnings.

Comment: Note that you don't use any mathematical functions, so including `<math.h>` and linking with `-lm` are both unnecessary.  Linking `-lm` before linking any of your object files is unreliable (not portable).  Put libraries after the object files (or source files if you compile direct to executable).  Please ensure you create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) (or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your program has mistakes as have been diagnosed by gcc in the screenshot provided.  You should not try to run a program that has such problems; instead fix the problems.

These are error conditions, as in your code does not comply with ISO C11 . The runtime behaviour of the program is not defined in any way as a result. Some compilers do not make life easy for the beginner by describing such conditions as "warnings".

---

The problem shown is that the function `strdup` is called which is not in ISO C11, but you have used the `-std=c11` flag. The "dcc" compiler is non-conforming if it does not give a diagnostic message for this call.

Possible fixes are:

- Use a different conformance mode that include strdup, e.g. `-std=gnu11`
- Manually prototype strdup (not really recommended but the correct form is: `char * strdup(const char *str1);`)
- Don't use `strdup`; instead use `malloc` followed by `strcpy`.
- Put as the first line of the source file `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700`, which will override `-std=c11` for that file.

Comment: Another option: explicitly enable POSIX or X/Open support by defining the appropriate macros before including any system headers.  `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` would pull in the definitions for POSIX 2008 (or later).  You could use `600` or even `500` and still get `strdup()`.  You could play with `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` instead, but the correct values are harder to remember (`200809L`, `200112L`, `199506L`).

Comment: Thanks you and everyone elses' help! After creating my own strdup, gcc compile and run no longer gives me seg fault.

Comment: @franklinH cool, although if you mean you wrote the function body yourself it would be a good idea to call it something else (e.g. `my_strdup`) to avoid clashes with other strdups that do exist in the system libraries , this can lead to hard-to-debug bugs